# Como listar os dados de uma query SQL agrupados por ordem de apresentação dos dados

Tags: sql, group-by

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de agrupar registros pela ordem de apresentação da pesquisa. Digamos que eu tenha uma tabela de dois campos Local (lugar mapeado), Time (Data e Hora). Local foi preenchido no mesmo lugar seguidamente em três tempos diferentes, depois tenho novos lugares e de volta ao mesmo lugar:

```
Recife   - 2016-08-15 13:59:44
Recife   - 2016-08-15 14:30:44
Recife   - 2016-08-15 15:59:44
SãoPaulo - 2016-08-15 19:00:00
Recife   - 2016-08-15 20:59:44
```

Nesse agrupamento surgiriam três linhas de resultado:

```
Recife   - 3
SãoPaulo - 1
Recife   - 1
```

Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Qual banco de dados? Poderia ser um Cursor?

Comment: Não vejo como. A não ser que você consiga fazer distinção entre esses registros para agrupa-los em grupos diferentes. Tipo: gravar no banco em qual leitura esses registros foram obtidos.

Comment: Veja se as respostas abaixo atende sua duvida e escolha uma como correta.

Comment: ---> Obrigada a todos pela atenção! ---> O banco é SQL Server (mas caso alguém conheça um código standard dá para adaptar), eu já faço pelo cursor queria saber se existia uma maneira de o agrupamento ser realizado desta forma sem a necessidade da criação da tabela temporária... Uma forma de aumentar a performance da minha pesquisa (esse exemplo que dei é bem simples, mas a quantidade de dados e de registros intercalados é bem maior).

Answer (score 3):

Caso seja, SQL Server, podemos agrupar utilizando a sintexe:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name;
```

Para utilizar o comando `GROUP BY` é necessario fornecedor uma função de agregação, ou seja, falar para o SQL Server, como ele deve agregar os campos que são iguais ao agrupar.

Exemplo:

Suponha uma tabela conforme abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quero agrupar a coluna `aliq_ipi`, faremos:

```
select aliq_ipi, count(ncm) from Ncm Group By aliq_ipi
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

Foi agrupado a coluna `aliq_ipi` contando a coluna `ncm`, ou seja, todos os `ncm` que tiverem o valor da coluna `aliq_ipi` iguais são agrupados.

Para seu caso podemos fazer:

```
SELECT cidade, count(data) FROM nomedatabela GROUP BY cidade
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria um curso, com tabelas temporárias para armazenar os dados de sua tabela física, isso ficaria assim;

```
declare @municipios table
(
  municipio varchar(100),
  data datetime
)

declare @municipios_teste table
(
  municipio varchar(100),
  total int
)

insert into @municipios values 
('Recife','2016-08-15 13:59:44'),
('Recife','2016-08-15 14:30:44'),
('Recife','2016-08-15 15:59:44'),
('SãoPaulo','2016-08-15 19:00:00'),
('Recife','2016-08-15 20:59:44')


declare @municipio varchar(100) ,@municipioold varchar(100) = '', @data datetime, @contador int = 0

DECLARE _cursor CURSOR FOR   
select * from @municipios

OPEN _cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM _cursor INTO @municipio  , @data

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    if(@contador = 0 or @municipioold = @municipio)
    begin 
         if(@contador = 0)
            set @contador = 1;
         else 
            set @contador += 1;

         set @municipioold = @municipio;

         delete @municipios_teste 
         where municipio = @municipio
         and total = @contador - 1;

         insert into @municipios_teste
         SELECT @municipio, @contador
    end 
    else 
    begin
        set @municipioold = @municipio;
        set @contador = 1;

        insert into @municipios_teste
        SELECT @municipio, @contador
    end 
    FETCH NEXT FROM _cursor INTO @municipio, @data  
    END  

CLOSE _cursor  
DEALLOCATE _cursor  


select * from @municipios_teste
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]